# Adafruit Huzzah Feather not resetting and serial monitor garbage

Tags: serial, esp8266, adafruit

[image: Fritzing circuit]

Hi there,

I have an Adafruit Huzzah Feather project laid out as you can see in the diagram above.

Currently I am having trouble getting it to reliably reset and start the sketch. More often than not I receive garbage in the serial monitor and the sketch doesn't begin.

The baud rate is set to 115200 and when the sketch occasionally I begin to see the expected behaviour and serial messages.

I have done some tests to see if the serial connection is causing a problem. I uploaded a sketch with and without `Serial.begin(115200);`. Without this the sketch behaves as expected (I'm flashing an LED sequence to know when the loop has begun). When I add serial communication back I get about 50/50 success rate when resetting.

Here are some thoughts about what could be the problem:

1. A problem with circuitry. Not sure if something is causing the board to occasionally activate the bootloader? After reading some of the FAQs I'm wondering if I'm accidentally pulling a GPIO pin low. However time has been spent making sure the problematic GPIO pins (0, 2 15) aren't being used.
2. Possible problem with the board itself - but this is unlikely because there are two of them with exactly the same problem.
3. Problem with the code. (https://pastebin.com/VAEreu6b)

Any thoughts and suggestions are very welcome at this stage.

Best,
Gareth

EDIT: Forgot to add code. Now here: https://pastebin.com/VAEreu6b

Comment: ... and the code is?

Comment: Ah yes! That would be helpful: https://pastebin.com/VAEreu6b

Comment: GPIO1 and 3 are used by serial, is there a conflict there?

Comment: GPIO1 isn't being used and 3 is connected to an accelerometer using i2c. Would that cause a problem?

Comment: @gfte yes it is the problem. pin 4 and 5 are default for I2C in esp8266 arduino core. the accelerometer library uses pin 3?

Comment: Serial is connected to USB, so pin 1 and 3 should not be used if USB communication is used